# Very large TRIM amounts

Tags: ssd, trim

Something is wrong with my system setup on SSD. During the installation of Ubuntu 14.04 I selected "use entire disc" for my 256 GB SSD.

Now after reload `fstrim` shows 200 GB trimmed and just after opening and closing Firefox with several tabs `fstrim` clears another 600 MB:

[image]

(I have 200 GB of free space and haven't deleted anything. Partition table is set to MSDOS (default). On the previous system installation (same version and same hardware, but manual partitioning) everything was fine.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your system or your SSD. The trim command allows the operating system to inform a solid state drive (SSD) which blocks of data are no longer considered in use and can be wiped internally. So as you have 200 GB of free space, only 200 GB can be trimmed.
Or the other way around, because you have 200 GB of free space, 200 GB are getting trimmed.

Comment: But why on previous setup amounts of TRIM data where much much lower with the same usage of computer? Maybe the reason is that last time i left somewhere like 20gb of unallocated space, and curently all available space is partitioned.

Comment: @user3120570 : Of course the unallocated space will not get trimmed, only ext4 file systems get trimmed. Sometimes the amount of trimmed space is not displayed correctly, but the trim command completes the action successfully nevertheless. So again, everything works just as it should ... nothing to worry about. :)

Comment: I still can't understand why on previous system it TRIMmed somewhere like 2.5-3 gb after all day usage, and now same amount is trimmed after 20 min usage. And how the amount of trimmed data can be displayed wrongly?

Comment: @user3120570 : You know the trim command at least is software, the developers improve it all the time and that is the reason why it now shows the amount correctly (compared to your old setup) - and as with every software, sometimes something doesn't work as expected, so just be glad that everything is okay. :)